# How to sum up the memory usage data from memory-profiler in Python?

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I have a question regarding the usage of the memory-profiler in Python.

I want to evaluate line-by-line on how much memory a function is using. However, the function is called multiple times and each would varying amount of memory usage.

I would like to have just one output at the end of the program that is the sum of all of the calls rather than multiple outputs for each function call.

Would this be possible using memory-profiler? Thank you.

Comment: What memory-profiler in Python?

Comment: @martineau This one: https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/